# preparing lapack dll with mingw

Tags: windows, dll, fortran, lapack

I downloaded lapack 3.3.0 version and mingw (with all libraries) after that I succeded to make blas.dll by `gfortran --shared -o blas.dll blas\src\*.f -O`
I could not succeeded to make lapack.dll by `gfortran --shared -o lapack.dll src\*.f blas.dll -O`

I got the following error

```
gfortran: error: CreateProccess: No such file or directory
```

Note: I set path to mingw/bin and also copied dlamch.f and slamch.f from install directory to src directory.

:: instructions got from this site

```
http://www.codingday.com/compile-lapack-and-blas-as-dll-on-windows/
```

What should I do

Comment: More details of the error please. Which file was `gfortran` processing? Is it a compiler or linker error? Does the error have context, e.g. line number?

Comment: No There is no any line number. just string that says createprocess: no file or directory. I doenst show any processing.... when I write gfortran --share lapack.dll bla bla  and pressing enter for 2 or 3 minutes later it shows an error that I mentioned before..

Answer (score 1):

I donwloaded lapack and can reproduce the error.
As is indicated in the comments on the page you referred to, you might be running into a problem with the command line being too long for the shell to handle. Try first compiling all source files, and then linking them, in two separate steps.

```
gfortran -c src/*.f -O
gfortran -shared -o lapack.dll *.o blas.dll
```

When I did this the `CreateProcess` error went away, but unfortunately some `undefined reference` errors popped up next. It appears there are references to a couple of blas functions which aren't included in the blas sources accompanying lapack (I think they might be C functions).

Comment: Yes I also tried that after you said. and have the same errors like
like "undefined reference to 'blas_cgbmv_x_' and so on and so for.. But how to solve this issue then?? :D

Comment: @nurmurat: I've had another look, but I can't readily solve that problem. You might want to edit your question to include it, or even start a new one for it.